# Getting this error in dot net :- CS8865 Only records may inherit from records

Tags: c#, .net-core, nopcommerce

When I'm using Nop Commerce version 4.50 to create a custom Plugin it is giving me this error. I can't understand why this error is coming i have used the same  method as in other Plugin.

With the help of this plugin i should be able to create a custom  plugin.[I have attached a picture for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mn5kC.png)

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Instead, copy the text itself, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74684545/edit) it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base class is apparently declared as

```
public record BaseNopModel {...}
```

You are inheriting from this, but a `class` cannot inherit from a `record`. Change the definition of your class to.

```cs
public record ConfigurationModel : BaseNopModel {...}
```

and that error will go away.

Comment: Thanks for the help it worked on my end the error is gone